# Does React Hook Form reduce rerenders when used with Conrolled Components like MUI TextField

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

[image]

As seen in the above picture react hooks form greatly reduces the rerenders and performs much better than formik. But when used with controlled components from UI libraries like material UI, would it still reduce rerenders and or rerender on every input change like Formik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes additional rerenders dont take place even when  is used. It can be seen here

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-controller-qsd8r

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can also use `formik-matierial-ui` package for bindings: https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui

Comment: That is not question that I asked